# JS Regex replacing left and right brackets individually

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to replace the square brackets in a string with different characters so they will escape correctly in SQL. For example, I need to replace [ with [[], and ] with []].

I've looked around but can only find solutions to replace a single bracket with a character, or replacing both with the same character, neither of which fits my need.

I can replace both in separate replace calls using regex, so to replace the left:

```
if (someString.value.indexOf('[') != -1) {
someString.value = someString.value.replace(/[\[']+/g, '[[]');
}
```

But obviously if I then try the same for the right bracket:

```
if (someString.value.indexOf(']') != -1) {
someString.value = someString.value.replace(/[\]']+/g, '[]]');
```

It will also take into account the extra brackets added in the first statement, which then completely messes up the string

how can I replace a string so for example, the following:

```
"[someText]"
```

will be replaced with:

```
"[[]someText[]]"
```

I should note that I need to replace any instance where there is text contained within square brackets, not just the first instance.

Comment: Thanks to Magus, the solution for me was:  someString.value = someString.value.replace(/[[]]/g, function(match) { return match == '[' ? '[[]' : ']'; });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function with `replace` :

```
someString.value = someString.value.replace(/[\[\]]/g, function(match) {
    return match == '[' ? '[[]' : '[]]';
});
```

Comment: +1 for beating me to the punch. i came up with a slightly different regex though: `"[someText]".replace(/(\[|])/g,function(match){ return match === "[" ? "[[]" : "[]]" })`

Comment: Thanks everyone, this was pretty much what I needed, apart from the fact I didn't need to escape the closing bracket. So for me the solution was:

    someString.value = someString.value.replace(/[\[\]]/g, function(match) {
    return match == '[' ? '[[]' : ']';
});